# What is the on-chip network topology of an Intel Core i7 (or i3 or i5) processor?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

What is the topology of the interconnection network within an Intel core i7, i3 or i5 processor? Is it using a:

- Crossbar
- Ring
- Hypercube
- Mesh
- Butterfly
- or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i7):

> Intel Core i7 as an Intel brand name applies to several families of desktop and laptop 64-bit x86-64 processors using the Nehalem, Westmere, Sandy Bridge, Ivy Bridge and Haswell microarchitectures.

Given such a long history, it is not especially surprising that more than one interconnect topology has been used. According to David Kanter's [article on Sandy Bridge](http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/8/), Nehalem and Westmere used a crossbar interconnect, while Sandy Bridge used a ring interconnect with four different rings: "request, snoop, acknowledge and a 32B wide data ring".

As David Kanter's article points out, using a ring interconnect makes flexibility in the number of interconnect nodes easier than if a crossbar was used.

According to page 6 of the 2012 IDF presentation "Technology Insight: Intel Next Generation Microarchitecture Code Name Haswell", Haswell retains the ring interconnect of Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge.

Answer (score 2):

It's known as Intel QuickPath Interconnect (QPI).  You can read Intel's whitepaper about it [here](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/white-paper/quick-path-interconnect-introduction-paper.pdf).

They describe it as "point to point" which is also how a [mesh topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking) is described.

Comment: The question was asking about *topology* not *protocol*.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Not my forte, but figure 6 appears to show the topology.  Intel describes it as "point to point", which is the same as the definition for a mesh topology.  I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: Since the OP was asking about Core i7, i3, i5, presumably he is not concerned with the off-chip (Xeon DP/MP) interconnect. With Xeon DP only two sockets are supported, so topology is somewhat moot. I seem to recall Xeon MP has three coherent QPI links, so a 3 socket system could have all-to-all, but a four socket system would look like a square with diagonal crossings (which provides more direct connections than a 2D-cube [which is the same as a 4 node mesh and a 4 node bidirectional ring]).